# How to catch unused variables with husky precommit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, husky

In my react/typescript project, I used **no-unused-variable** rule with tslint. So if there are no unused variables or imports it will block the commit. Now it says that, it has been deprecated and use **noUnusedLocals** and **noUnusedParameters* in tsconfig file.

I used it like this.

```
"compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es6",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    // other rules
```

}

Now the unused variables are highlighted as warnings, but the precommit cannot catch them.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you fix this?

Comment: yes. I will post the answer.

Comment: Hi @Shashika, can you post answer?